# Unable to import Numpy after fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, pip

I'm running a fresh installation of **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**. I've done nothing to the python installation(s) except trying to install `numpy`, using `pip3`

I'm behind a proxy, so I've installed `numpy` by

```
magnus$ sudo pip3 --proxy http://my.proxy.com:99 install numpy`
```

... which worked smoothly.

Then, I tried,

```
magnus$ python3 -c "import numpy"
```

which leads to a looong error message, summerized as

```
...
Original exception was:
...
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'local'
```

The `pip3 list` commands tells me that `numpy (1.17.3)` is installed, but not `threading`

If I look into the `/usr/lib/python3.6` directory, I find `threading` but not `numpy`, However,

```
magnus$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
```

shows only two directories, namely `numpy` and `numpy-1.17.3.dist-info`.

I suspect there are some issues about installing python packages for *local* or *all* users, but I can't figure out how I messed this up, or how to fix it.

**EDIT**: Importing `threading` instead of `numpy` results in the exact same error message.

Comment: Interesting, it may be that when numpy is loaded, it attempts to import threading.local() but just fails. It may be a disagreement on versions. Have you tried installing Threading with pip3 as well?

Comment: @BobserLuck Yes, it fails with `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/threading`, but this test gave some progress! `import threading` fails with the same error message, so the problems is with `threading`, and not the installation of `numpy`: Updating my post.

Answer (score 0):

*Embarrassing:* This issue was caused by myself, polluting the `threading` namespace. I had a python file (in my working dir), named **threading.py** which obviously came in conflict with the module of the same name. Thus, all modules using the `threading` package failed on import, `numpy` included. Simply renaming my local file to something else solved the problem entirely.

This issue was also posted and solved on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920771/ubuntu-10-04-python-multiprocessing-module-object-has-no-attribute-local).